# is there any quick way to utilise an activity as a service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, autostart

I have a ginormously huge activity whose primary task is to just upload audio files and images from some particular folders. but not, in short, it's needed to perform this in the background , as a service.
I'm not looking for some step-by-step answer, just someone with experience to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Activity and Service are two different components in android.To execute background tasks as your case, you could use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService), read https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service is also helpful.

google it and there are numberous examples.